# Rest API invoke from java struts application java version 1.5 code with weblogic 11g server

Tags: soap

Please help me sample code for invoke Restful API in our web application that is developed in java 1.5 version with weblogic 11g server

Please help me sample code for invoke Restful API in our web application that is developed in java 1.5 version with weblogic 11g server